# How to scale tikzpicture table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, matrices

I need to scale this table to smaller size, all together with color boxes.
I was not able to do it with scale command. Any help? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] \centering \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1.5pt] \matrix [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3pt, column sep=-2.2pt, nodes={anchor=east}] (m) { 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 \\ 90 & 90 & 88 & 85 & 82 & 78 & 73 & 67 & 61 & 54 & 46 & 38 & 31 & 22 & 13 & 4 &
-4 & -13 & -22 & -31 & -38 & -46 & -54 & -61 & -67 & -73 & -78 & -82 & -85 & 88 & -90 & -90 \\ 90 & 87 & 80 & 70 & 57 & 43 & 25 & 9 & -9 & -25 & -43 & -57 & -70 & -80 & -87 & -90 & -90 & -87 & -80 & -70 & -57 & -43 & -25 & -9 & 9 & 25 & 43 & 57 & 70 & 80 & 87 & 90 \\ 90 & 82 & 67 & 46 & 22 & -4 & -31 & -54 & -73 & -85 & -90 & -88 & -78 & -61 &
-38 & -13 & 13 & 38 & 61 & 78 & 88 & 90 & 85 & 73 & 54 & 31 & 4 & -22 & -46 & -67 & -82 & -90 \\ 89 & 75 & 50 & 18 & -18 & -50 & -75 & -89 &
-89 & -75 & -50 & -18 & 18 & 50 & 75 & 89 & 89 & 75 & 50 & 18 & -18 & -50 & -75 & -89 & -89 & -75 & -50 & -18 & 18 & 50 & 75 & 89 \\ 88  & 67  & 31  & -13  & -54  & -82  & -90  & -78  & -46  & -4  & 38  & 73  & 90  & 85  & 61  & 22  & -22  & -61  & -85  & -90  & -73  & -38  & 4  & 46  & 78  & 90  & 82  & 54  & 13  & -31  & -67  & -88 \\ 87  & 57  & 9  & -43  & -80  & -90  & -70  & -25  & 25  & 70  & 90  & 80  & 43  &
-9  & -57  & -87  & -87  & -57  & -9  & 43  & 80  & 90  & 70  & 25  & -25  & -70  & -90  & -80  & -43  & 9  & 57  & 87  \\ 85  & 46  & -13  & -67  & -90  & -73  & -22  & 38  & 82  & 88  & 54  & -4  & -61  & -90 & -78  & -31  & 31  & 78  & 90  & 61  & 4  & -54  & -88  & -82  & -38  & 22  & 73  & 90  & 67  & 13  & -46  & -85   \\ 83  & 36  & -36  & -83 & -83  & -36  & 36  & 83  & 83  & 36  & -36  & -83  & -83  & -36  & 36 & 83  & 83  & 36  & -36  & -83  & -83  & -36  & 36  & 83  & 83  & 36  & -36  & -83  & -83  & -36  & 36  & 83   \\ 82  & 22  & -54  & -90  &
-61  & 13  & 78  & 85  & 31  & -46  & -90  & -67  & 4  & 73  & 88  & 38  & -38  & -88  & -73  & -4  & 67  & 90  & 46  & -31  & -85  & -78  & -13  & 61  & 90  & 54  & -22  & -82   \\ 80  & 9  & -70  & -87  &
-25  & 57  & 90  & 43  & -43  & -90  & -57  & 25  & 87  & 70  & -9  & -80  & -80  & -9  & 70  & 87  & 25  & -57  & -90  & -43  & 43  & 90  & 57  & -25  & -87  & -70  & 9  & 80   \\ 78  & -4  & -82  & -73  & 13  & 85  & 67  & -22  & -88  & -61  & 31  & 90  & 54  & -38  & -90  & -46 & 46  & 90  & 38  & -54  & -90  & -31  & 61  & 88  & 22  & -67  & -85  & -13  & 73  & 82  & 4  & -78   \\ 75  & 18  & -89  & -50  & 50  & 89  & 18  & -75  & -75  & 18  & 89  & 50  & -50  & -89  & -18  & 75  & 75  & -18  & -89  & -50  & 50  & 89  & 18  & -75  & -75  & 18  & 89  & 50  & -50  & -89  & -18  & 75   \\ 73  & -31  & -90  & -22  & 78  & 67  &
-38  & -90  & -13  & 82  & 61  & -46  & -88  & -4  & 85  & 54  & -54  & -85  & 4  & 88  & 46  & -61  & -82  & 13  & 90  & 38  & -67  & -78  & 22  & 90  & 31  & -73   \\ 70  & -43  & -87  & 9  & 90  & 25  & -80  & -57  & 57  & 80  & -25  & -90  & -9  & 87  & 43  & -70  & -70  & 43  & 87  & -9  & -90  & -25  & 80  & 57  & -57  & -80  & 25  & 90  & 9  &
-87  & -43  & 70   \\ 67  & -54  & -78  & 38  & 85  & -22  & -90  & 4  & 90  & 13  & -88  & -31  & 82  & 46  & -73  & -61  & 61  & 73  & -46  & -82  & 31  & 88  & -13  & -90  & -4  & 90  & 22  & 85  & -38  & 78  & 54  & -67   \\ 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64   \\ 61  & -73  & -46  & 82  & 31  & -88  & -13  & 90  & -4  & -90  & 22  & 85  & -38  & -78  & 54  & 67  & -67  & -54  & 78  & 38  & -85  & -22  & 90  & 4  & -90  & 13  & 88  & -31  & -82  & 46  & 73  & -61   \\ 57  & -80  & -25  & 90  & -9  & -87  & 43  & 70  & -70  & -43  & 87  & 9  & -90  & 25  & 80  & -57  & -57  & 80  & 25  & -90  & 9  & 87  & -43  & -70  & 70  & 43  & -87  & -9  & 90  & -25  & -80  & 57   \\ 54  &
-85  & -4  & 88  & -46  & -61  & 82  & 13  & -90  & 38  & 67  & -78  & -22  & 90  & -31  & -73  & 73  & 31  & -90  & 22  & 78  & -67  & -38  & 90  & -13  & -82  & 61  & 46  & -88  & 4  & 85  & -54   \\ 50  & -89 & 18  & 75  & -75  & -18  & 89  & -50  & -50  & 89  & -18  & -75  & 75 & 18  & -89  & 50  & 50  & -89  & 18  & 75  & -75  & -18  & 89  & -50  & -50  & 89  & -18  & -75  & 75  & 18  & -89  & 50   \\ 46  & -90  & 38  & 54  & -90  & 31  & 61  & -88  & 22  & 67  & -85  & 13  & 73  &
-82  & 4  & 78  & -78  & -4  & 82  & -73  & -13  & 85  & -67  & -22  & 88  & -61  & -31  & 90  & -54  & -38  & 90  & -46   \\ 43  & -90  & 57 & 25  & -87  & 70  & 9  & -80  & 80  & -9  & -70  & 87  & -25  & -57  & 90  & -43  & -43  & 90  & -57  & -25  & 87  & -70  & -9  & 80  & -80 & 9  & 70  & -87  & 25  & 57  & -90  & 43   \\ 38  & -88  & 73  & -4  & -67  & 90  & -46  & -31  & 85  & -78  & 13  & 61  & -90  & 54  & 22  & -82  & 82  & -22  & -54  & 90  & -61  & -13  & 78  & -85  & 31  & 46 & -90  & 67  & 4  & -73  & 88  & -38   \\ 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  &
-36  & 83  & -83  & 36  & 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  & -36  & 83  & -83  & 36  & 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  & -36  & 83  & -83  & 36  & 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  & -36  & 83  & -83  & 36   \\ 31  & -78  & 90  & -61  & 4 & 54  & -88  & 82  & -38  & -22  & 73  & -90  & 67  & -13  & -46  & 85 & -85  & 46  & 13  & -67  & 90  & -73  & 22  & 38  & -82  & 88  & -54  & -4  & 61  & -90  & 78  & -31   \\ 25  & -70  & 90  & -80  & 43  & 9  & -57  & 87  & -87  & 57  & -9  & -43  & 80  & -90  & 70  & -25  & -25 & 70  & -90  & 80  & -43  & -9  & 57  & -87  & 87  & -57  & 9  & 43  &
-80  & 90  & -70  & 25   \\ 22  & -61  & 85  & -90  & 73  & -38  & -4  & 46  & -78  & 90  & -82  & 54  & -13  & -31  & 67  & -88  & 88  & 67  & 31  & 13  & -54  & 82  & -90  & 78  & -46  & 4  & 38  & -73  & 90  &
-85  & 61  & -22   \\ 18  & -50  & 75  & -89  & 89  & -75  & 50  & -18  & -18  & 50  & -75  & 89  & -89  & 75  & -50  & 18  & 18  & -50  & 75  & -89  & 89  & -75  & 50  & -18  & -18  & 50  & -75  & 89  & -89  & 75 & -50  & 18   \\ 13  & -38  & 61  & -78  & 88  & -90  & 85  & -73  & 54  & -31  & 4  & 22  & -46  & 67  & -82  & 90  & -90  & 82  & -67  & 46  & -22  & -4  & 31  & -54  & 73  & -85  & 90  & -88  & 78  & -61  & 38  & -13   \\ \:\:9  & -25  & 43  & -57  & 70  & -80  & 87  & -90  & 90  & -87  & 80  & -70  & 57  & -43  & 25  & -9  & -9  & 25  & -43  & 57  & -70  & 80  & -87  & 90  & -90  & 87  & -80  & 70  & -57  & 43  &
-25  & 9   \\ 4  & -13  & 22  & -31  & 38  & -46  & 54  & -61  & 67  & -73  & 78  & -82  & 85  & -88  & 90  & -90  & 90  & -90  & 88  & -85  & 82  & -78  & 73  & -67  & 61  & -54  & 46  & -38  & 31  & -22  & 13  & -4   \\ }; \begin{scope}[on background layer] \node[fill=GreenYellow,inner sep=4.5pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-32-32)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-3-1) (m-3-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-5-1) (m-5-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-7-1) (m-7-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-11-1) (m-11-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-13-1) (m-13-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-15-1) (m-15-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-17-1) (m-17-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-19-1) (m-19-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-21-1) (m-21-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-23-1) (m-23-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-25-1) (m-25-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-27-1) (m-27-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-29-1) (m-29-16)] {}; \node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-31-1) (m-31-16)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-8)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-5-1) (m-5-8)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-8)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-13-1) (m-13-8)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-17-1) (m-17-8)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-21-1) (m-21-8)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-25-1) (m-25-8)] {}; \node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-29-1) (m-29-8)] {}; \node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-4)] {}; \node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-4)] {}; \node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-17-1) (m-17-4)] {}; \node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-25-1) (m-25-4)] {}; \end{scope} \end{tikzpicture}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently the table fits quite perfectly into the page width if you use a `table*` instead of `table`. Even with an extremely small font size you will most likely not be able to fit the table into one of the two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just append `scale=1.5,transform shape` to the nodes, or some other scale factor.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] \centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1.5pt]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3pt, column sep=-2.2pt, 
nodes={anchor=east,scale=1.5,transform shape} %<changed
] (m) 
{ 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 & 64 \\ 
 90 & 90 & 88 & 85 & 82 & 78 & 73 & 67 & 61 & 54 & 46 & 38 & 31 & 22 & 13 & 4 & -4 & -13 & -22 & -31 & -38 & -46 & -54 & -61 & -67 & -73 & -78 & -82 & -85 & 88 & -90 & -90 \\ 
 90 & 87 & 80 & 70 & 57 & 43 & 25 & 9 & -9 & -25 & -43 & -57 & -70 & -80 & -87 & -90 & -90 & -87 & -80 & -70 & -57 & -43 & -25 & -9 & 9 & 25 & 43 & 57 & 70 & 80 & 87 & 90 \\
 90 & 82 & 67 & 46 & 22 & -4 & -31 & -54 & -73 & -85 & -90 & -88 & -78 & -61 & -38 & -13 & 13 & 38 & 61 & 78 & 88 & 90 & 85 & 73 & 54 & 31 & 4 & -22 & -46 & -67 & -82 & -90 \\
 89 & 75 & 50 & 18 & -18 & -50 & -75 & -89 & -89 & -75 & -50 & -18 & 18 & 50 & 75 & 89 & 89 & 75 & 50 & 18 & -18 & -50 & -75 & -89 & -89 & -75 & -50 & -18 & 18 & 50 & 75 & 89 \\
 88  & 67  & 31  & -13  & -54  & -82  & -90  & -78  & -46  & -4  & 38  & 73  & 90  & 85  & 61  & 22  & -22  & -61  & -85  & -90  & -73  & -38  & 4  & 46  & 78  & 90  & 82  & 54  & 13  & -31  & -67  & -88 \\
 87  & 57  & 9  & -43  & -80  & -90  & -70  & -25  & 25  & 70  & 90  & 80  & 43  &-9  & -57  & -87  & -87  & -57  & -9  & 43  & 80  & 90  & 70  & 25  & -25  & -70  & -90  & -80  & -43  & 9  & 57  & 87  \\
 85  & 46  & -13  & -67  & -90  & -73  & -22  & 38  & 82  & 88  & 54  & -4  & -61  & -90 & -78  & -31  & 31  & 78  & 90  & 61  & 4  & -54  & -88  & -82  & -38  & 22  & 73  & 90  & 67  & 13  & -46  & -85 \\
 83  & 36  & -36  & -83 & -83  & -36  & 36  & 83  & 83  & 36  & -36  & -83  & -83  & -36  & 36 & 83  & 83  & 36  & -36  & -83  & -83  & -36  & 36  & 83  & 83  & 36  & -36  & -83  & -83  & -36  & 36  & 83   \\
 82  & 22  & -54  & -90  & -61  & 13  & 78  & 85  & 31  & -46  & -90  & -67  & 4  & 73  & 88  & 38  & -38  & -88  & -73  & -4  & 67  & 90  & 46  & -31  & -85  & -78  & -13  & 61  & 90  & 54  & -22  & -82   \\
 80  & 9  & -70  & -87  & -25  & 57  & 90  & 43  & -43  & -90  & -57  & 25  & 87  & 70  & -9  & -80  & -80  & -9  & 70  & 87  & 25  & -57  & -90  & -43  & 43  & 90  & 57  & -25  & -87  & -70  & 9  & 80   \\
 78  & -4  & -82  & -73  & 13  & 85  & 67  & -22  & -88  & -61  & 31  & 90  & 54  & -38  & -90  & -46 & 46  & 90  & 38  & -54  & -90  & -31  & 61  & 88  & 22  & -67  & -85  & -13  & 73  & 82  & 4  & -78   \\
 75  & 18  & -89  & -50  & 50  & 89  & 18  & -75  & -75  & 18  & 89  & 50  & -50  & -89  & -18  & 75  & 75  & -18  & -89  & -50  & 50  & 89  & 18  & -75  & -75  & 18  & 89  & 50  & -50  & -89  & -18  & 75   \\
 73  & -31  & -90  & -22  & 78  & 67  &-38  & -90  & -13  & 82  & 61  & -46  & -88  & -4  & 85  & 54  & -54  & -85  & 4  & 88  & 46  & -61  & -82  & 13  & 90  & 38  & -67  & -78  & 22  & 90  & 31  & -73   \\
 70  & -43  & -87  & 9  & 90  & 25  & -80  & -57  & 57  & 80  & -25  & -90  & -9  & 87  & 43  & -70  & -70  & 43  & 87  & -9  & -90  & -25  & 80  & 57  & -57  & -80  & 25  & 90  & 9  &-87  & -43  & 70   \\
 67  & -54  & -78  & 38  & 85  & -22  & -90  & 4  & 90  & 13  & -88  & -31  & 82  & 46  & -73  & -61  & 61  & 73  & -46  & -82  & 31  & 88  & -13  & -90  & -4  & 90  & 22  & 85  & -38  & 78  & 54  & -67   \\ 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64  & 64   \\ 61  & -73  & -46  & 82  & 31  & -88  & -13  & 90  & -4  & -90  & 22  & 85  & -38  & -78  & 54  & 67  & -67  & -54  & 78  & 38  & -85  & -22  & 90  & 4  & -90  & 13  & 88  & -31  & -82  & 46  & 73  & -61   \\ 57  & -80  & -25  & 90  & -9  & -87  & 43  & 70  & -70  & -43  & 87  & 9  & -90  & 25  & 80  & -57  & -57  & 80  & 25  & -90  & 9  & 87  & -43  & -70  & 70  & 43  & -87  & -9  & 90  & -25  & -80  & 57   \\ 
 54  & -85  & -4  & 88  & -46  & -61  & 82  & 13  & -90  & 38  & 67  & -78  & -22  & 90  & -31  & -73  & 73  & 31  & -90  & 22  & 78  & -67  & -38  & 90  & -13  & -82  & 61  & 46  & -88  & 4  & 85  & -54   \\
 50  & -89 & 18  & 75  & -75  & -18  & 89  & -50  & -50  & 89  & -18  & -75  & 75 & 18  & -89  & 50  & 50  & -89  & 18  & 75  & -75  & -18  & 89  & -50  & -50  & 89  & -18  & -75  & 75  & 18  & -89  & 50   \\
 46  & -90  & 38  & 54  & -90  & 31  & 61  & -88  & 22  & 67  & -85  & 13  & 73  & -82  & 4  & 78  & -78  & -4  & 82  & -73  & -13  & 85  & -67  & -22  & 88  & -61  & -31  & 90  & -54  & -38  & 90  & -46   \\ 
 43  & -90  & 57 & 25  & -87  & 70  & 9  & -80  & 80  & -9  & -70  & 87  & -25  & -57  & 90  & -43  & -43  & 90  & -57  & -25  & 87  & -70  & -9  & 80  & -80 & 9  & 70  & -87  & 25  & 57  & -90  & 43   \\
 38  & -88  & 73  & -4  & -67  & 90  & -46  & -31  & 85  & -78  & 13  & 61  & -90  & 54  & 22  & -82  & 82  & -22  & -54  & 90  & -61  & -13  & 78  & -85  & 31  & 46 & -90  & 67  & 4  & -73  & 88  & -38   \\
 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  & -36  & 83  & -83  & 36  & 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  & -36  & 83  & -83  & 36  & 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  & -36  & 83  & -83  & 36  & 36  & -83  & 83  & -36  & -36  & 83  & -83  & 36   \\
 31  & -78  & 90  & -61  & 4 & 54  & -88  & 82  & -38  & -22  & 73  & -90  & 67  & -13  & -46  & 85 & -85  & 46  & 13  & -67  & 90  & -73  & 22  & 38  & -82  & 88  & -54  & -4  & 61  & -90  & 78  & -31   \\
 25  & -70  & 90  & -80  & 43  & 9  & -57  & 87  & -87  & 57  & -9  & -43  & 80  & -90  & 70  & -25  & -25 & 70  & -90  & 80  & -43  & -9  & 57  & -87  & 87  & -57  & 9  & 43  &-80  & 90  & -70  & 25   \\
 22  & -61  & 85  & -90  & 73  & -38  & -4  & 46  & -78  & 90  & -82  & 54  &
 -13  & -31  & 67  & -88  & 88  & 67  & 31  & 13  & -54  & 82  & -90  & 78  & -46  & 4  & 38  & -73  & 90  & -85  & 61  & -22   \\ 18  & -50  & 75  & -89  & 89  & -75  & 50  & -18  & -18  & 50  & -75  & 89  & -89  & 75  & -50  & 18  & 18  & -50  & 75  & -89  & 89  & -75  & 50  & -18  & -18  & 50  & -75  & 89  & -89  & 75 & -50  & 18   \\ 13  & -38  & 61  & -78  & 88  & -90  & 85  & -73  & 54  & -31  & 4  & 22  & -46  & 67  & -82  & 90  & -90  & 82  & -67  & 46  & -22  & -4  & 31  & -54  & 73  & -85  & 90  & -88  & 78  & -61  & 38  & -13   \\ \:\:9  & -25  & 43  & -57  & 70  & -80  & 87  & -90  & 90  & -87  & 80  & -70  & 57  & -43  & 25  & -9  & -9  & 25  & -43  & 57  & -70  & 80  & -87  & 90  & -90  & 87  & -80  & 70  & -57  & 43  &-25  & 9   \\ 
 4  & -13  & 22  & -31  & 38  & -46  & 54  & -61  & 67  & -73  & 78  & -82  & 85  & -88  & 90  & -90  & 90  & -90  & 88  & -85  & 82  & -78  & 73  & -67  & 61  & -54  & 46  & -38  & 31  & -22  & 13  & -4   \\ 
 }; 
\begin{scope}[on background layer] 
\node[fill=GreenYellow,inner sep=4.5pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-32-32)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-3-1) (m-3-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-5-1) (m-5-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-7-1) (m-7-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-11-1) (m-11-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-13-1) (m-13-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-15-1) (m-15-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-17-1) (m-17-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-19-1) (m-19-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-21-1) (m-21-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-23-1) (m-23-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-25-1) (m-25-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-27-1) (m-27-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-29-1) (m-29-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=WildStrawberry,inner sep=3pt,fit=(m-31-1) (m-31-16)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-5-1) (m-5-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-13-1) (m-13-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-17-1) (m-17-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-21-1) (m-21-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-25-1) (m-25-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Yellow,inner sep=1.5pt,fit=(m-29-1) (m-29-8)] {}; 
\node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-1-1) (m-1-4)] {}; 
\node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-9-1) (m-9-4)] {}; 
\node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-17-1) (m-17-4)] {}; 
\node[fill=Turquoise,inner sep=0pt,fit=(m-25-1) (m-25-4)] {}; 
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```